# Random reverse output sqlx on Golang

Tags: go, sqlx

Using sqlx in Golang with this code:

```
rows, err := db.Queryx(`SELECT "SIGN_ID","SIGN_NAME" FROM sign`)
 for rows.Next() {
    results := make(map[string]interface{})
    err = rows.MapScan(results) 
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", results)
}
```

The result looks really promising:

```
map[string]interface {}{"SIGN_ID":"JD", "SIGN_NAME":"John Doe"}
map[string]interface {}{"SIGN_ID":"JAD", "SIGN_NAME":"Jane Doe"}
map[string]interface {}{"SIGN_ID":"DD", "SIGN_NAME":"Donald Duck"}
map[string]interface {}{"SIGN_NAME":"Chris Walker", "SIGN_ID":"CW"} <----
map[string]interface {}{"SIGN_ID":"SN", "SIGN_NAME":"St Nicolas"}
```

Two questions:

1. Why does one line random "reverse" the output order <----:

> map[string]interface {}{"SIGN_NAME":"Chris Walker", "SIGN_ID":"CW"}

2. How can I get rid of the prefix: **map[string]interface {}**

Comment: You have two entirely unrelated questions here: 1. is about map ordering in Go. 2. is about formatting complex data structures when printing. This should be asked as two questions. And incidentally, neither actually has anything at all to do with sqlx.

Answer (score 1):

1. [It is known behaviour](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21095). Keys are randomly ordered in golang map.
2. Use `fmt.Printf("%v\n", results)`

Comment: Better, but replaced with "map". map[SIGN_ID:JD SIGN_NAME:John Doe] and the double quotes disappeared.

Comment: I think the most appropriate solution for you would be to iterate over the map by yourself and print it in any format is suites for you.